# How to display posts of taxonomy in WordPress page template?

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure if this has been asked before, but I'm a bit lost. I've created a "Newsroom" Pods with a custom taxonomy of Newsroom Category. Newsroom Category has 3 fields: Press Release, Media, Others. I have a WordPress page template: `taxonomy-newsroom_category.php`

`taxonomy-newsroom_category.php` is used to display Pods posts if meets the following:

```
1 - pods = 'newsroom'
2 - taxonomy = 'press_release' || 'media' || 'others'
```

My issue right now is that I can't find a way to display the post details:
`image(thumbnail)`, `title(post title)`, `date_published`

I hope someone can help. Thanks

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
<?php
                //Setup Pod object
                //Presuming permalink structure of example.com/pod-name/item-name
      //See http://pods.io/code/pods/find
                //Set $params to get 5 items

                $params = array(
          'limit' => 5,
        );

        //get current pod name
        $pod_name = pods_v( 0, 'newsroom');
        //get pods object
        $pods = pods( $pod_name, $params );

        //check that total values (given limit) returned is greater than zero
        if ( $pods->total() > 0 ) {
          //loop through items using pods::fetch
          while ($pods->fetch() ) {
            //Put title/ permalink into variables
            $post_title = $pods->display('post_title');
            $date_published = $pods->display('date_published');
            $permalink = site_url( trailingslashit( $pod_name ) . $pods->field('permalink') );
        ?>
                        <div class="news-item col-sm-4">
                            <div class="news-item-img"></div>
                            <div class="news-item-header">
                                <h5 class="news-category"></h5>
                                <h2 class="news-item-title"><a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></h2>
                                <h5 class="news-item-date"><?php echo $date_published; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- close -->
                <?php
          } //endwhile;
        } //endif;

        // Output Pagination
        //see http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/pagination
        echo $pods->pagination( );
        ?>
```

Comment: What's your code inside the taxonomy template?

Answer (score 1):

I also found out solution for that... I had my Custom Post Type "studies" and I had to filter them, based on custom taxonomy category. If you want to write Posts of one taxonomy category, try to use something like that:

```
$type = $_GET['type'];

$args = array(
        "post_type" => "studien",
        "post_per_page" => -1,
        "relation" => "AND"
);


if($type != "") {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(

        'taxonomy' => 'market',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $type
    );

 $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

}
```

`$type` represents one category in my created Taxonomy (value comes from HTML code in select option), `$args` Is some query on database and 'market' is slug of my custom Taxonomy, `$wp_query` returns all filter Posts

[image: Market Taxonomy in Custom Post Type Studien]

screenshot of my custom taxonomy in custom post type. As you can see, I have two groups. First is clicked in two Posts and Second is clicked in last two Posts. Maybe it will helps you to give imagination

Comment: thanks! i've tried your sample but it didn't give me any result. found this somewhere else though:                                     
`<?php
 $type = $_GET['type'];

 $args = array(
   "post_type" => "newsroom",
   "post_per_page" => -1,
   "relation" => "AND"
 );

 if($type != "") {
  $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                                          'taxonomy' => 'newsroom_category',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => $type
  );

  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);                                                                 
        }
?>`

Comment: In my example I registered custom taxonomy, which has two categories, but you need to assign some category for your Post. otherwise it will return all your Posts of your Custom Post Type... first of all try to var_dump $wp_query (whether something is returned or not)

Comment: Is assigning category for each post the same as assigning taxonomy terms? say I have 5 posts: 2 post = media, 1 post = others, 2 = press_release

Comment: It depends, what exactly comes from option value. For example, my option values is 'Group One', so code return only posts which have taxonomy category 'Group One'

Comment: I see. Sadly, I can't even display anything right now. And I'm just getting more lost than ever. I've been continuously searching and testing other ways, but other scripts needs to indicate the specific terms, and I didn't want to do that in case other admins adds in new terms. Then it wouldn't display in the taxonomy page.

Comment: @mchk check my answer, I gave update with screenshot

Comment: Yepp, I have the same setup as your screenshot. And still, I can't display the taxonomy categories under "newsroom_category".

Comment: first of all, post your code for displaying all Posts.. then we will move forward

Comment: I'm using exactly a copy of the archive.php I just want to customize the way it displays my custom post type posts.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters. This document explained how to query with custom post type and taxonomy in details. Youd code could be something like this.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'newsroom',
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'newsroom_category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'press_release',
      ),
  ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID(); // with post id, you can get whatever you want.
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: thanks! i've yet to try this. but i've got another question, is it possible not to indicate the specific term? like if active term is equal to terms then display all posts?

Comment: Yes, use [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) to get the whole list of terms first, then build 'tax_query' withe the term list.

Comment: I've tried your code and it doesn't seem to be displaying anything for me.

Answer (score -1):

from the wordpress documenation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Taxonomies

we have the below , for taxonomy person

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'person',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bob'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );