# How can I dynamically filter the choices in a taxonomy select Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

More specifically – I have multi-select taxonomy field A. When one or more values are selected in A, I want to restrict the choices available in taxonomy field B.

So for example:

Two Taxonomies called

country - "USA", "Russia", "China"

city - "Chicago", "Moscow", "Beijing"

I want when user in taxonomy "country" choose value "USA" after that in taxonomy "city" show only "chicago". Is it possible? And how can I do this?

is there wordpress plugin that does this?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, try to get inspiration in my answer on that question, it should helps you: [How to display posts of taxonomy in WordPress page template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550230/how-to-display-posts-of-taxonomy-in-wordpress-page-template/52552313?noredirect=1#comment92110816_52552313)